# Develop ANE with Facebook iOS 4.16.1 SDK for Adobe Air mobile, any successful story?

Tags: ios, actionscript, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am also working on an ane development named xfFB which is base on Facebook SDK 4 over iOS. I put the code below as native library for login:

```
  [self dispatchEvent:@"LOGIN_IN_PROGRESS" withMessage: @"iOS login to facebook..."];
  FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];

  [login
   logInWithReadPermissions: permissions fromViewController:nil // block below is either not executed or not interacting with the actionscript.
   handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
   if (error) {
   NSLog(@"Process error");
  [xfFB dispatchEvent:failed withMessage:[error localizedDescription]];
  } else if (result.isCancelled) {
   NSLog(@"Cancelled");
  [xfFB dispatchEvent:success withMessage:@"CANCEL"];
  } else {
  NSLog(@"Logged in");
  NSString *jsonString =[self obj2Json: (NSObject *)result];
  [xfFB dispatchEvent:success withMessage: jsonString];
  }
  }];
```

---

The code did awake Facebook native app but just simply return to my as3 app without execute the handler block. I am wondering that whether the fb 4.x SDK can be integrated with ActionScript or not since it takes in charge too many controls to let the app itself to get involve in the process. Does someone has an example?

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish the login, I found a callback will go the as3 app with a INVOKE event after executing the code above. 
You as3 app should listen to that event, then you need to open the returned url with your app's delegate for authorization. (still don't know why is the code in the block not executed, but anyhow, now I get the access token and can access the user profile)

Comment: be careful in handling the received invoke, not only the url but also the option keys. Now the code inside the block is executed when correct option keys pass to the delegate. This should compliant to the fb sdk documents